# Ubuntu White Screen after sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*

Tags: nvidia

I'm new to ubuntu 14 and have been having a lot of problems with my desktop freezing.  I think it is related to the nvidia graphics.  The screen sometimes replaces words with horizontal lines, sometimes becomes checkered where all the graphics are off, or sometimes horizontal lines appear.  These problems are followed with the computer freezing.  I can push ctrl Alt F1 and ctrl Alt F7 or ctrl Alt F2 and ctrl Alt F7 and most of the time it will unlock.  Sometimes this has to be repeated several times before the graphics completely starts working again. Sometimes this does not help and I need to push the power button. I've tried to lower my resolution on the screen.  Also I've removed dual monitors. Recently it is happening about every minute and I can not complete any of my work.

I saw on a post with a similar issue to try the following commands after pushing ctrl Alt F2:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I tried this.  However, sadly now I'm in way worse shape.  I only get a white screen while starting the computer.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I wish I could supply more information about the specs of the computer to help in the post but I can not get past the white screen.

Comment: Next time, don't do this. You can just switch between video drivers by searching for Additional Drivers. I'll post a possible fix as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Reboot. Once you get into the bootloader menu (GRUB), choose `Advanced Options for Ubuntu`.
2. Select a Recovery Kernel (doesn't matter which).
3. In the list of options that then comes up, select `failsafe graphics mode`.
4. This should boot you into Ubuntu and should let you use it, but with low-res graphics. Now you need to reinstall the generic drivers.
5. Open Unity Dash (the search menu) and search for `Additional Drivers`.
6. Open the resulting application and let it scan.
7. Once it finishes scanning, select the generic Xorg driver. It should be obvious which it is.

If this doesn't work, I'll delete my answer. No need to downvote.

Comment: Unfortunely the computer freezes at step 3

Comment: OK. Try dropping to a root shell (option, `root` in the recovery options). Tell me when you get there.

Comment: Sorry I went home for the night. This problem is on my work computer.  Can I get back to you tomorrow?

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Comment: Hello Zacharee1,  I was able to get to the root.